# How to convert string type value into int type value in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

**I need to convert a string into an int type, so i can perform my operation**

```
 >>> t="'2000'"
 >>> int(t)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'1'"
```

Comment: `int("'2000'".strip("'")` should do it. `"TAT".strip("T")` returns "A"  - all the given characters to strip are removed from start and end of string

Answer (score 3):

You have a double quoted string, in the error message it warns you about thr `'` beeing a illegal number for conversion. Either clean your string to `t="10"` removing the redundant quotes or strip the string if received from else where int(t[1:-1]).

Comment: so how should i convert double quoted string to single string? because this is the one of the value given data set.

Comment: You get the string `'2000'` with `t="'2000"` as a result, so you want to omit the first and the last character of the string, leaving it as `2000`. In python you can slice a string by taking a range of the string (by the braces `[]`) with a from-to range as from character to character (i.e. `[1:5]` giving the secound to the sixt char of a string), you can also reverse index with `-1` being the last char in the string, so `t[1:-1]` gives you all the string but the first and last char and converts the rest to string ^^

Answer (score 1):

`t` is a string with the value of `'2000'`. You are looking to make `t` a string with only the number `2000` by doing `t = "2000"`. With `int()` you are trying to convert the apostrophes to ints as well which you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse the string `'2000'` into an int, which it is not since there are quotes around the `2000`. You can change the code to this to make it work:

```
t = "'2000'"
t = t[1:-1]
int(t)
```

Comment: but this value is given me in my data set problem.so i can't change this my own.

Comment: @Bhaskararya Take a look at the answer from @paulwurtz, you can do `int(t[1:-1])` with `t` being `t = "'2000'"` and it will work aswell.

Comment: Look on my answer, but for short: strip the string if received from else where `int(t[1:-1])`

Comment: can you tell me how to make double quoted string to single quoted string?